# Datepicker: Show days from next/prev month (if in ending/starting week of current one)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, customization

This is how datepicker shows a month by default, numbers start the first of the month and end the last of the month:

[image]

The thing is that I need to fill the whole calendar with numbers, like this:

[image]

So I found that the option `showOtherMonths` to `true` does the trick:

[image]

But if you notice, it adds an extra week, Wich I dont need,

Any idea why?

-EDIT-

The whole code:

```
jQuery('.datepicker').each(function (i) {
    var $item = jQuery(this);
    var fechas = $item.data('fechas') != '' ? $item.data('fechas') : '';    
    var urls = $item.data('urls') != '' ? $item.data('urls') : '';
    var tipos = $item.data('tipos') != '' ? $item.data('tipos') : '';
    var titulos = $item.data('titulos') != '' ? $item.data('titulos') : '';
    var options = {
        'dateFormat' : dateFormat,
        'display' : $item.data('display') == '' ? '' : $item.data('display'),
        firstDay: 1,
        numberOfMonths: $item.data('months') == '' ? 1 : $item.data('months'),
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: false
    }
    /* Marcar los dias con sesion */
    if (fechas.length) {
        options.beforeShowDay = function(datestr) {
            var fecha = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, datestr);
            var arr = [true, ''];
            for( var j = 0 ; j < fechas.length ; j++ ) {  
                if ( fecha == fechas[j] ) {
                    return [true, 'dia-con-evento '+tipos[j], titulos[j], 'link'];
                } 
            }
            return arr;
        }
    }       
    /* Agregar links a los días */
    options.onSelect = function (datestr) {
        if ( fechas.indexOf(datestr) != -1 ) {
            location.href =  urls[ fechas.indexOf(datestr) ];                   
        }
    }   
    $item.datepicker( options );
});
```

Markup:

```
<div class="datepicker year" 
             data-display="inline"
             data-fechas='["13\/05\/2015","11\/02\/2015","11\/03\/2015","10\/06\/2015","08\/04\/2015","08\/07\/2015","30\/03\/2015","30\/03\/2015","04\/05\/2015","04\/05\/2015","14\/05\/2015","24\/05\/2015","03\/06\/2015","18\/06\/2015","28\/06\/2015","03\/06\/2015","03\/06\/2015","13\/06\/2015","07\/07\/2015","08\/07\/2015","09\/07\/2015","07\/08\/2015","17\/08\/2015","15\/11\/2015"]'
             data-urls='["\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=sesion\/1","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=sesion\/2","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=sesion\/3","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=sesion\/4","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=sesion\/5","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6"]'
             data-tipos='["caso","caso","caso","caso","caso","caso","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito"]'
             data-titulos='["El tratamiento del asma: \"a la carta\" vs \"menu\u0301 del di\u0301a","El caso del Sr. Minotaruro en el laberinto de los ARA II","A vueltas con el protector...","El humor es como el colesterol, unos tienen del bueno, otros del malo","Deprescripcio\u0301n: En busca de la cordura","Mesa redonda BBPP Premio 1a edicio\u0301n","Programaci\u00f3n del caso en La Ventana","Preparaci\u00f3n del materia","Preparaci\u00f3n del materia","Entrega del material","Aprobaci\u00f3n del material y lanzamiento de la sesi\u00f3n cl\u00ednica","Reuni\u00f3n de preproducci\u00f3n","Grabaci\u00f3n","Validaci\u00f3n del v\u00eddeo","Validaci\u00f3n del v\u00eddeo","Publicaci\u00f3n de material en la plataforma de eformaci\u00f3n","Validaci\u00f3n del material en la plataforma de eformaci\u00f3n","Validaci\u00f3n del material en la plataforma de eformaci\u00f3n","Publicaci\u00f3n de v\u00eddeo en web y plataforma","Emisi\u00f3n de la sesi\u00f3n cl\u00ednica","Apertura m\u00f3dulos eformaci\u00f3n","Finalizaci\u00f3n del curso","Presentaci\u00f3n de alumnos aprobados","Pago a ponente"]'  
             data-months='6'
        >
        </div>
```

Comment: the option 'showOtherMonths' probably will show others months isn't?

Comment: show your code to see what you have.

Comment: When will your variable "fechas" have any code?

Comment: if you comment out your conditional "if (fechas.length)...", do you still get the error?

Comment: Fechas allways have code, I am putting a sample in the question @CodeGodie

Comment: ok. Where is `dateFormat` (inside your variable options) defined?

Comment: dateFormat could be any: `dd/mm/yyyy` for example ;) @CodeGodie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems to be running fine. If the problem persists, i would assume is a different type of script or CSS conflicting with what you have already, perhaps an outdated jquery library.

```js
$('.datepicker').each(function (i) {
    var $item = $(this);
    var fechas = $item.data('fechas') != '' ? $item.data('fechas') : '';    
    var urls = $item.data('urls') != '' ? $item.data('urls') : '';
    var tipos = $item.data('tipos') != '' ? $item.data('tipos') : '';
    var titulos = $item.data('titulos') != '' ? $item.data('titulos') : '';
    var options = {
        'dateFormat' : "dd/mm/yyyy",
        'display' : $item.data('display') == '' ? '' : $item.data('display'),
        firstDay: 1,
        numberOfMonths: $item.data('months') == '' ? 1 : $item.data('months'),
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: false
    }
    
    /* Marcar los dias con sesion */
    
    if (fechas.length) {
        options.beforeShowDay = function(datestr) {
            var fecha = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yyyy", datestr);
            var arr = [true, ''];
            for( var j = 0 ; j < fechas.length ; j++ ) {  
                if ( fecha == fechas[j] ) {
                    return [true, 'dia-con-evento '+tipos[j], titulos[j], 'link'];
                } 
            }
            return arr;
        }
    }       
   
    /* Agregar links a los días */
    
    options.onSelect = function (datestr) {
        if ( fechas.indexOf(datestr) != -1 ) {
            location.href =  urls[ fechas.indexOf(datestr) ];                   
        }
    }   
       
    $item.datepicker( options );
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="datepicker year" 
             data-display="inline"
             data-fechas='["13\/05\/2015","11\/02\/2015","11\/03\/2015","10\/06\/2015","08\/04\/2015","08\/07\/2015","30\/03\/2015","30\/03\/2015","04\/05\/2015","04\/05\/2015","14\/05\/2015","24\/05\/2015","03\/06\/2015","18\/06\/2015","28\/06\/2015","03\/06\/2015","03\/06\/2015","13\/06\/2015","07\/07\/2015","08\/07\/2015","09\/07\/2015","07\/08\/2015","17\/08\/2015","15\/11\/2015"]'
             data-urls='["\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=sesion\/1","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=sesion\/2","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=sesion\/3","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=sesion\/4","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=sesion\/5","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6","\/sescam-la-ventana\/?q=caso\/6"]'
             data-tipos='["caso","caso","caso","caso","caso","caso","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito","hito"]'
             data-titulos='["El tratamiento del asma: \"a la carta\" vs \"menu\u0301 del di\u0301a","El caso del Sr. Minotaruro en el laberinto de los ARA II","A vueltas con el protector...","El humor es como el colesterol, unos tienen del bueno, otros del malo","Deprescripcio\u0301n: En busca de la cordura","Mesa redonda BBPP Premio 1a edicio\u0301n","Programaci\u00f3n del caso en La Ventana","Preparaci\u00f3n del materia","Preparaci\u00f3n del materia","Entrega del material","Aprobaci\u00f3n del material y lanzamiento de la sesi\u00f3n cl\u00ednica","Reuni\u00f3n de preproducci\u00f3n","Grabaci\u00f3n","Validaci\u00f3n del v\u00eddeo","Validaci\u00f3n del v\u00eddeo","Publicaci\u00f3n de material en la plataforma de eformaci\u00f3n","Validaci\u00f3n del material en la plataforma de eformaci\u00f3n","Validaci\u00f3n del material en la plataforma de eformaci\u00f3n","Publicaci\u00f3n de v\u00eddeo en web y plataforma","Emisi\u00f3n de la sesi\u00f3n cl\u00ednica","Apertura m\u00f3dulos eformaci\u00f3n","Finalizaci\u00f3n del curso","Presentaci\u00f3n de alumnos aprobados","Pago a ponente"]'  
             data-months='6'
        >
        </div>
```

Comment: In this example there is one extra row being added for the month of June. (4-10). Any idea on what needs to be done for removing that.

Answer (score 2):

**DEMO: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/2403/)**

Try this:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true
});
```

Please show more of your code, to give you a more in depth answer.